# create function based index with rrrr date format

Tags: sql, oracle

I have problem of create function based index with 'RR' date format

**note**: this is only scenario its not my original sql query

```
create table chkdt(frdt date,todt date);

insert into chkdt(frdt,todt)values('01-jun-2015','01-sep-2015');

select frdt,todt from chkdt where to_date('01-may-1991','dd-mm-rrrr') between frdt and todt;

create  index fbi_fmrdt on chkdt(to_date(frdt,'dd-mm-rr'));
```

> ORA-01743: only pure functions can be index

so how to create ?

Thanks & Regards
J@ysh.

Comment: You should never call `to_date` on a `date`.  That doesn't make sense.  You could create a regular index on `frdt`.  But whether you're using a function-based index or not, it wouldn't be used for the query you posted.

Comment: i am tuning like this type of query using oem 10g they recommendation..

Comment: I don't understand what "this type of query" means.  Does "they" in "they recommendation" refer to "OEM 10g"?  What, specifically, is OEM recommending?

Comment: i am new oracle dba and my sr.dba give me one sql query and this sql query is same scenario of my original sql query(this is not original sql query) .he give me this sql query with oracle enterprise manager sql tunning through recommendations create function based index or improve this sql query perfomance , so thats why i am asking to same scenario type of create.

Comment: It makes no sense to create a function-based index for a query that isn't using a function.  It makes no sense to call `to_date` on a `date`.  And, as written, I'm hard-pressed to think of many indexes that would be particularly useful for the query you posted.

Comment: ok i understand..what are you saying...thanks for help.

Comment: If you have a problem with a slow query, then post the complete query and the execution plan (as **formatted** text).